# React Native - Router Flux - Empty Scene For Key Error

Tags: ios, uitableview, react-native, react-native-router-flux, react-native-ios

I am getting an error when using the following code in my index.ios.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Actions, Router, Route, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import {Categories} from './Components/Categories';
import {CarRacing} from './Components/CarRacing';

const scenes = Actions.create(
  <Scene key="root">
      <Scene key="Categories" name="Categories" component={Categories} title="Categories" initial={true}/>
      <Scene key="CarRacing" name="CarRacing" component={CarRacing} title="CarRacing"/>
  </Scene>
);

export default class Motorsport extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router scenes={scenes}/>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Motorsport', () => Motorsport);
```

Categories are a list of categories in a tableview done by 'react-native-tableview'. When clicking on the the CarRacing TableView row, I get the following error:

```
route.children.forEach is not a function. (In 'route.children.forEach(function(r,i) {(0,_Util.assert)(scenes[r],'Empty scene for key='+route.key);if*scenes[r].inital) {index=i;}})','route.children.forEach' is undefined)
```

I am not sure what I have done wrong here. I understand the error, but I don't quite get what I did in my code to mess this up.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: make sure from where you getting the error. attach screen shot if possible

Comment: Above code looks okay for me

Comment: Weird that it works, I must have something different somewhere.
This is the screenshot @Ashok
[Screenshot](https://i.imgsafe.org/7f7554d4b7.png)

Comment: post your answer what makes it works?

Comment: Nothing yet @Ashok - I can't get it to work. That's why I was saying weird that it works for you.